# Library for a simple graphics application - Android

Tags: android, canvas, view, graphics, opengl-es

I am creating a simple graphics application, where the user can draw several shapes, change the shape color-size, zoom, rotate the device etc. After researching, I found out that there are many options on how this can be achieved and I find it hard to choose which approach would benefit me more. One approach that I have started testing is to create a [custom view and to draw on Canvas](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html).

Is this option valuable in order to proceed without having the futuristic fear of low performance resulting to switch over something else (e.g. something like [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html))?

Or better, given the brief description above, what would you recommend as the **best option**?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As this is an opinion based type of question, I think this one might get closed, so I'll type fast: I think to get your app up and running fast, `Canvas` is your best approach (lots of easy docs and examples out there), unless you're already an export in OpenGL, to which there is quite a steep learning curve. It doesn't sound like, from your app requirements, you would hit upon any serious performance issues, and, as I say, you can get thing running quickly. If performance is not adequate, you can latter switch to pure OpenGL or use a framework for it like libGDX, Rajawali, AndEngine, etc.

Comment: I have no experience in openGL, neither on _Canvas_. I am only afraid of Canvas's performance but I will most likely begin with this approach and see how it goes (hope of not having bad results in performance).